# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES for Nox Player

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I have a low-end PC in which I develop Android applications and deploy them on the emulator. Since I have a low-end PC, I use NoxPlayer which is according to me the fastest. I installed it yesterday. Android Studio detects Nox but when I run the application, a error named INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES doesn't allow the app to run. There is no error on physical device but when I run it on Nox, I get this error.

Similar emualtors like Genymotion and Bluestacks work but my PC is not designed for them and Genymotion hangs a lot. I have tried configuring my Gradle file, Invalidate caches, reinstall it but no fix.  Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to File > Project Structure > Then go to Modules > Default Config > Then scroll down till you see the Signing Config then select the only available option then the problem will be solved

Comment: Go to android view on android studio, and type

gradlew signingReport